# how to write if condition

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

```
public void myServletInit(RequestParameters r){
r.setFormValidator("myFormXml")
}
r.setFormValidator("myForm2Xml");
```

I have 2 XML files to validate, myformXml contains Fname,  Lname,and dob.myForm2Xml contain id. when I'm sending input through HTTP request that contains id, FName, LName, and dob. so if I'm sending id as input myform2xml should be validated else myformxml validate.

please help me to how to perform this condition

I tried below code:

```
public void myServletInit(RequestParameters r,  HttpServletRequest h){
String id = h.getParameter("id")
 if(id != null)
{
r.setFormValidator("myForm2Xml");
}else{r.setFormValidator("myFormXml");}
```

Comment: `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` gets a request parameter not a node from XML document. You need to parse the XML somehow to get the nodes.

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki,  public void myServletInit(RequestParameters r){
r.setFormValidator("myFormXml")
} this is my previous code working fine. now I added new xml file want to choose one file based on my Id, if id not null r.setFormValidator("myForm2Xml") will excecute, how should i write the if condition for this.